# Consultar producto mayor vendido en base de datos por cantidad SQL

Tags: sql, microsoft-sql

Estoy tratando de conseguir el nombre del producto que mas se ha vendido por cantidad  en mi base de datos
he probado:

```
SELECT Nombre_Producto 
FROM Productos WHERE (Id_Producto,Cantidad) IN 
( SELECT Id_Producto, MAX(cantidad)
  FROM Detalle_Factura
  GROUP BY Id_Producto

select Nombre_Producto sum(Detalle_Factura.Cantidad) as cantidad from Detalle_Factura join Productos on Detalle_Factura.Id_Producto = Productos.Id_Producto
```

Lo unico que he podido sacar de manera directa es el numero maximo de un producto vendido en la otra tabla:

```
select max(Cantidad) as maxima_cantidad from Detalle_Factura
```

se que necesito enlazar estos datos pero no encuentro como. Cualquier aporte es muy agradecido

[image: DIagrama de la base de datos]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Podrias intentar como opcion, porque no es la unica forma, hacer un select a los productos, y hacer un `CROSS APPLY` que de forma sencilla de explicar te permitiria hacer una "Sub Consulta" de donde hagas el `SUM` de los totales de las facturas donde se encuentre el producto, y los ordenas descendentement por su cantidad

```
SELECT TOP 1
P.Nombre_Producto,
TOTALES.cantidad
FROM Productos as P
CROSS APPLY(
    SELECT SUM(DF.Cantidad) as cantidad 
    FROM Detalle_Factura as DF
    WHERE DF.Id_Producto = P.Id_Producto
) as TOTALES
ORDER BY TOTALES.cantidad DESC
```

Desconosco si funcionara por no tener datos, pero espero te sirva como ejemplo de como podrias usar `CROSS APPLY`